# Socket.io integration in micro service express gateway

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, microservices, express-gateway

I am working on micro-service through the express gateway and I just want to integrate socket.io.

I have already integrated the socket.io to my one microservice and I need to connect that socket to my all other microservices.

How can I send a socket object connection from one node service to another node service?

Please help

Comment: Is it your intention to use Express Gateway between the sockets?

Comment: Yes, I am using the express gateway, now I want socket interaction between two microservices.

Comment: What do you need to do this for? It sounds like a lot of additional complexity over just using Express Gateway for inter-service communication.

Comment: I want to integrate socket.io on the express gateway .yml file so that we can integrate one scoket.io connect in every microservice for communication between microservice as well as frontend.

Comment: I think it would be better (less coupled) to have the Microservices communicate through Express Gateway rather than introducing a separate communication path. I think you’ll have to hack EG to do this, and it seems like a lot of work for no real benefit over using http or https via Express Gateway for inter-microservice communication.